# Arguments object is not showing correct result

Tags: javascript

look at this code

```
enter code here
function foo(a, b) {
    arguments[1] = 2;
    alert(b);
}

console.log(foo(1));
```

Its showing `undefined` I am not able to understand why..
because when we pass arguents

```
foo(1) `arguments[0]=1` right.?
```

And when we `alert(b)` it should display 2 because we set  `arguments[1] = 2`;
I am confused.. please help. Thanks.

Comment: no i am not running in strict mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually adding elements into `arguments` will not set the setters and getters properly. Not even `.length` will update.

```
function foo(a, b){
    arguments[1] = 2;
    console.log(arguments.length);   //1
}

foo(1);
```

Summary: Don't add elements to `arguments`. Remember, `arguments` is not an Array.

Comment: you mean we can not modifiy the arguments passed by using Arguments object?

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini Yes you can, as long as they already existed in the `arguments` object.

Comment: But here arguments[1] dosen't exits because we have not passed it right?

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini Right.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - Careful.  `arguments[0]` is only aliased back to `a` if `a` was originally passed in AND you are not running strict mode.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for the tip. I don't exactly know what the expected behavior would be in strict mode, but I think this is a simple enough answer for general use :)

Answer (score 0):

Only the original arguments that existed when the function was called are "aliased" through the `arguments` object such that you could change the arguments object and have it automatically affect the named function argument also.

FYI, in strict mode, none of the items on the `arguments` object are aliased back to the named function arguments.  But, in non-strict mode, the arguments that originally existed (and only those) are aliased back through the `arguments` object.

Keep in mind that the arguments object is not a real Array.  It is a special type of object and this special "aliasing" behavior only exists for the properties of that object that were originally placed there when the function was called, not for properties that you might have added yourself.  Since `arguments[1]` did not originally exist, it does not have this special feature.

See this:

```
function foo(a, b) {
    console.log(arguments.length);    // 1
    arguments[1] = 2;
    console.log(arguments.length);    // still 1
    console.log(arguments[1]);        // does show 2
    console.log(b);                   // undefined, arguments[1] is not aliased to b
}

console.log(foo(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense that `b` remains `undefined`. When you run `foo(1)`, it initializes `a` to `1` and `b` to `undefined`. Modifying the `arguments` object won't change that. That is, `b` is not *bound* to `arguments[1]`.